# Invoking a function on text click: AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to invoke a specific controller method when click on some text. This function makes some remote calls to another server and configure showing or hiding another div. I also need to pass some parameters to such functions, one of which is static text and the other is a angularJS variable (i.e. an element of a list I am iterating on.

I am not sure the best way to do it, as the following code does not seem to work:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in item_list">
    <div ><p ng-click="functionToInvoke({{item.name}}, 
                      'static text')">{{item.name}}</p></div>
```

I get a compile error on the paragraph.

How do I manage this situation?

Comment: if you have tried the answer and had a problem, comment on the answer. You have updated your question to match the answer and not given details of the error you are receiving.

Comment: @manu Do not edit your question to reflect an answer given, it is VERY confusing for anyone reading this and reflects badly on the person who has tried to help you with a valid answer. Give details to the answer you have received about your compile error.

Comment: I was already modifying the post when the answer arrived. So, i just went back to the original question in order to leave it of reasonable help to the rest of the world. I've just realized I forgot to re-add the brackets around the ng-Click when restoring the first question version. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When specifing a function in `ng-click` you dont need `{{}}`

```
<div ng-repeat="item in item_list">
    <div >
        <p ng-click="functionToInvoke(item.name, 'static text')">{{item.name}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your function then looks something like this:

```
$scope.functionToInvoke = function(var, static){
    console.log('This is the variable:' + var);
    console.log('This is the static:' + static);
}
```